# Surjectivity of a linear transformation from the space of all formal power series to itself

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

> Today, one of my friends asked that if we take the linear transformation $T : P(\mathbb{R}) \to P(\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $T(p(x))=p(x)+p''(x)$, then $T$ is onto or not. $P(\mathbb{R})$ is the vector space of all formal power series.

My attempt :
If we take a polynomial $q(x) \in P(\mathbb{R})$, then we can form a differential equation 
                       $p''(x)+p(x)=q(x)$.
But is it solvable ?? The confusion rises since $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are all formal power series.

I've tried to check the coefficients and compare them, but it doesn't help in any way. 
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Whether that equation has a solution or not does not really have much to do with whether your map is linear or not. What did you get by writing the definition of linearity?

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't about linearity, it asks to show surjectivity. @DanielLittlewood

Comment: By definition a polynomial has finite degree. If you mean what I think you mean by "polynomial of infinite degree" you should really call them _formal  power series_.

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Ullrich. I'm gonna edit it soon.

Comment: @AnikBhowmick Sorry I just checked the edit history and it looks like I simply misread it. My bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trivial that this map is surjective.

We need to show this:  Given any sequence $(a_0,a_1,\dots)$ there exists a sequence $(b_0,b_1,\dots)$ such that $$2b_2+b_0=a_0,$$ $$6 b_3+b_1=a_1,$$
$$12b_4+b_2=a_2,$$etc.

Let $b_0=b_1=0$. Solve the first equation for $b_2$. Solve the second equation for $b_3$. *Since* we have determined $b_2$ we can solve the third equation for $b_4$. Etc.

Comment: But is it okay to assume $b_0 = b_1 =  0$ ?

Comment: I didn't say "assume $b_0=b_1=0$, I said "let $b_0=b_1=0$. We're trying to show that _there exists_ a sequence $(b_n)$ with a certain property. In showing that I can define $b_n$ any way I like, as long as the sequence I define satisfies the equations.

Comment: David, you can’t consider such a space without any more précisions. Concerning derivability or convergence for instance.

Comment: @Pjonin Huh? It sounds like you have no idea what the phrase "formal power series" means. Convergence has nothing to do with anything I said. There's no problem defining the (formal) derivative of a formal power series. The derivative of $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots$ is $a_1+2a_2x+\dots$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I know exactly what is formal power series. You don’t need to be agressive. However, the author changed « polynomial » for « formal series » in his post.

Comment: No, he changed "polynomial of infinite degree" to "formal power series". At the start of the first version of my answer I _said_ I was talking about formal power series. You should read the first sentence before making bogus corrections.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is surjective.

Given $$ q(x) = b_0 + b_1x + b_2x^2 + ....$$

You like to find a power series $P(x)$  such $$P''(x)+P(x)=q(x)$$

Let $$P(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3+....$$

$$ P''(x) +P(x) = (a_0+2a_2) + (a_1+6a_3)x +(a_2+12a_4)x^2 +....$$

$$ q(x) = b_0 + b_1x + b_2x^2 + ....$$
We need to solve 
$$ a_0+2a_2=b_0$$

$$a_1+6a_3=b_1$$

$$a_2+12a_4=b_2$$

You will find many solutions for $P(x)$

Answer (score -1):

Please be careful with the difference between a polynomial and the function associated with it. 
You should write $T(P)=P+P´´$
The idea would be to consider the matrix of your endomorphism in $R_{n}[X]$ in the usual basis to see if it is invertible or not.

Edit : remember that derivation is a linear operation.

Comment: Sorry, I can't get it. Would you please elaborate yourself ??

Comment: First, do you understand that you can’t take $P(x)$ in $R[X]$ ? It is a number not a polynomial. It is the polynomial $P$ evaluated in x. You need to be familiar with it.

Comment: But is it possible to find an inverse of an infinite ordered square matrix ??

Comment: No but in a space of finite dimension such as $R_n[X]$ yes.

Comment: Okay, it means that the $T$ is not onto. Thanks !!

Comment: Of course it is onto. Please show me your results.

Comment: Since it forms an infinite ordered square matrix, then how can I get the inverse ??

Comment: Please take the time to read my comments. I won’t be responding any further.

Comment: Okay, for the matrices of certain pattern, it is possible to find inverse. Can we do it for an arbitrary matrix of infinite order ??

Comment: The question has nothing to do with $R_n[X}$ or $R[X}$. The question is about $R[[X]]$.

Comment: Again, the question was about polynomials at the beginning.

Comment: It was about "polynomials of infinite degree". Whatever that might mean, the elements of $R[X]$ are certainly not polynomials of infinite degree.

Comment: Ineed the initial title meant nothing and i understood it as R[X], which seems to be a mistake.